# Getting input from input function, and running a function using that letter

Tags: python

I know this is possible with the eval() function, but, it does **NOT** work in my program. I have no clue why. So, is there another way? Here is some code: I am looking for a simple way, as I am new to python programming. Really new... I have tried eval() but it just returns an error. I have been at this for hours now, and haven't found an answer online. If this is relevant, I use repl.it turtle.

```
import turtle

from time import sleep
ninja = turtle.Turtle()
ninja.hideturtle()
coordinate1 = ninja.xcor()
coordinate2 = ninja.ycor()
new1=''
new2=''

ninja.speed(10)
def h():
  ninja.left(90)
  ninja.forward(50)
  ninja.back(100)
  ninja.forward(50)
  ninja.right(90)
  ninja.forward(35)
  ninja.left(90)
  ninja.forward(-50)
  ninja.forward(100)
  coordinate1 = ninja.xcor()
  coordinate2 = ninja.ycor()
  new1 = coordinate1+50

  ninja.penup()
  ninja.goto(new1,0)

def i():
  ninja.forward(20)
  ninja.pendown()

  ninja.left(90)

  ninja.st()
  ninja.right(90)
  ninja.stamp()

  ninja.ht()
  ninja.penup()
  ninja.back(20)
  ninja.pendown()
  ninja.back(50)



  coordinate1 = ninja.xcor()

  new1 = coordinate1+50

  ninja.penup()
  ninja.goto(new1,0)



h()
i()
name = input('What is your name. It will be drawn in the tab to the left lowercase only please.')
print('The name will begin to draw in the tab to the left')
sleep(3)
ninja.clear()
ninja.goto(0,0)

name =  list(name)
print(name)
length = len(name)
x=0
while (x < length-1):         
  print(name[x])
  x = x + 1

  new2=name[x]+'()'
  eval(new2)
  print(new2)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is wrong when you try to run it? I don't see `eval` in your code, so I'm not sure what you need to fix.

Comment: If you find out a way to make it work using eval(), please tell me. I have been trying to use that

Comment: Sorry I was experimenting let me add it

Comment: You just posted code and said "it doesn't work". But I don't know what you are trying to do. It's like if I said: I tried `5` and it didn't work. You would need to know I was trying to add `2 + 2` and I should have gotten `4`.

Comment: Ok. I want someone to enter their name, then it will draw it with turtle. I will split up the name into an array, and then run the function of one letter of it. For example: BOB=['B', 'O', 'B'] Then it runs function B, then O, then B again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary:

```
letter_movements = {'h': h, 'i': i}
```

Then, when you want to run the function (where you have eval) simply pick from the dictionary:

```
letter_movements[new2]()
```

Comment: It's annoying because you have to create the dictionary just to translate strings to python code, but it also protects your code from user input.